# Convert a Hexadecimal Input to a Binary and count all 1s -Java

Tags: java, binary, hex

I need help, this is my assignment. How to count the 1s only in Binary of the given hexadecimal input. It gives me the numbers of how many 1 and 0 in binary.

```
    package javaapplication3;
import java.util.*;
public class JavaApplication3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         System.out.println("Enter the string you want printed : ");
         Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
         String s = sc.next();
         int duck = 0;
         byte[] bytes = s.getBytes();
         StringBuilder binary = new StringBuilder();
         for (byte b : bytes){
             int val = b;
             for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
                 binary.append((val & 128) == 0 ? 0 : 1);
                 val <<= 1;
                if( val != 1) {
                    duck++;
             }
            }
             binary.append(' ');
         }
         System.out.println("'" + s + "' to binary: " + binary);
         System.out.println("Number of bit 1 in string: " + duck); 
}
}
```

It gives me an output:

> Enter the string you want printed :  BABEFACE
>
> 'BABEFACE' to binary: 01000010 01000001 01000010 01000101 01000110
>   01000001 01000011 01000101
>
> Number of bit 1 in string: 64
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 10 seconds)

Comment: Do not use dirty words in code!

Answer (score 0):

Ummm

**BABEFACE** as binary looks like
**1011 1010 1011 1110 1111 1010 1100 1110** to me...

and the number of 1s should be **24**

the way to go tp solve this could be:

1. parse the string to hex
2. convert to bin
3. count the 1s or 0s

## Example:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    Long l = Long.parseLong("BABEFACE", 16);
    String hexAsBin = Long.toBinaryString(l.longValue());
    System.out.println(hexAsBin);
    System.out.println("Number of 1: " + countChars(hexAsBin, "1"));
    System.out.println("Number of 0: " + countChars(hexAsBin, "0"));
    }

    private static int countChars(String hexAsBin, String x) {
    return hexAsBin.length() - hexAsBin.replace(x, "").length();
    }
```

Comment: You're thinking of Hex values as `0xBA 0xBE 0xFA 0xCE`, but I think Asker is working with ASCII char codes (hex value of each character), hence the differences in yours & his binary string.

Answer (score 0):

To check for all "1"s in your string, just use a `for` loop to check. It will be fastest (compared to `String` functions & Regular Expressions etc).

example:

```
String binary = "";
binary = "01000010 01000001 01000010 01000101 01000110 01000001 01000011 01000101";

int counted_Ones = 0;

//# check "ones" in string
for( int i=0; i<binary.length(); i++ ) 
{ if(binary.charAt(i) == '1') { counted_Ones++; } }

System.out.println("binary: " + binary);
System.out.println("Number of bit 1 in string: " +  counted_Ones);
```

Results (from `System.out.println`) :

> binary: **01000010 01000001 01000010 01000101 01000110 01000001
>   01000011 01000101** 
>  Number of bit 1 in string: **20**